# Iterate parallel loop dynamic stage based on text file content jenkins pipeline

Tags: arrays, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm a newbie to jenkins dsl groovy scripting. i have a parameterized jenkins job which takes two inputs $param1 $param2
I have two stages. First stage generates output.txt file which has contents like below in the workspace. The output.txt file changes content based on shell script execution in stage1. So, the values are dynamic
output.txt

```
svn-test
svn_prod
svn_dev
```

Second stage has to get input from the file output.txt and iterate in a parallel loop dynamically creating stages. I have the below code but it doesn't take input from output.txt file. I'm unable to overirde the array in the stage and iterate parallely

```
def jobs = []
def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
script{
git credentialsId: 'github', url: 'ssh://github.com/promp/${job}.git', branch: master
                echo "This is ${job}."
                sh ''' make ${parameter1}@"${paramete2}" '''
               }
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any
parameters {
        parameters {
        string(name: 'parameter1', defaultValue: 'UIAutomation', description: 'Please enter the value')
    string(name: 'parameter2', defaultValue: 'UISite', description: 'Please enter the value')
    }
    stages {
        stage('non-parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {  
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
                sh '''./rotate_script.sh output.txt'''
                }
            }
        }
        stage('parallel stage') {
            failFast false
            steps {
                script {
                    def filePath = readFile('output.txt').trim()
                    def lines = filePath.readLines()
                    line.each {
                    // I have tried to read lines and pass it value. It didn't workout``
                    }
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally this is how my one of the second stage looks like and create multiple parallel stages based on output.txt file

```
stage('svn-test'){
        steps{
            sh 'mkdir -p svn-test'
          dir("svn-test"){
        script{
            git credentialsId: 'github', url: 'ssh://github.com/promp/svn-test.git', branch: master
            sh ''' make ${parameter1}@"${parameter2}"
            '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got something like this to work.  I had to move my Groovy List and the `parallelStageMap` into my pipeline. The `StageMap` is getting set at the start of your script when your list is empty, thus you are never getting any results.  If you move it AFTER the list is populated it will work.

```
def generateStage(job) {
    return {
        stage("stage: ${job}") {
            script{
                git credentialsId: 'github', url: 'ssh://github.com/promp/${job}.git', branch: master
                echo "This is ${job}."
                sh ''' make ${parameter1}@"${paramete2}" '''
            }
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
         string(name: 'parameter1', defaultValue: 'UIAutomation', description: 'Please enter the value')
         string(name: 'parameter2', defaultValue: 'UISite', description: 'Please enter the value')
    }
    stages {
        stage('non-parallel stage') {
            steps {
                script {  
                    echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
                    sh '''./rotate_script.sh output.txt'''
                }
            }
        }
        stage('parallel stage') {
            failFast false
            steps {
                script {
                    def jobs=[]
                    def filePath = readFile('output.txt').trim()
                    def lines = filePath.readLines()
                    lines.each { job ->
                        jobs.add("${job}")
                    }
                    def parallelStagesMap = jobs.collectEntries {
                        ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
                    }
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).